# Inflating a xml layout in a custom View class

Tags: android, view, android-inflate

I have a class `View1` that extends `View`. I want to inflate `R.layout.test2.xml` in this class `View1`. I have put a following code in this class

```
public class View1 extends View {

    View view;
    String[] countries = new String[] {"India", "USA", "Canada"};

    public View1( Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater  mInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.test2, null, false);
    }
}
```

From another class `Home` I want this inflated view to be there for some circumstances , In the `Home` class I wrote the following code:

```
public class Home extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        CreateView();   
    }

    public void CreateView() {
        LinearLayout lv=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
        View1 view = new View1(Home.this);
        lv.addView(view);
    }
}
```

But as I run my project the activity doesn't show me anything.

Answer (score 53):

You can't add views to the `View` class instead you should use `ViewGroup` or one of its subclasses(like `Linearlayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc). Then your code will be like this:

```
    public class View1 extends LinearLayout {

        View view;
        String[] countries = new String[] {"India", "USA", "Canada"};

        public View1( Context context) {
            super(context);
            inflate(context, R.layout.test2, this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell why we it was giving nothing by extending View.

Comment: @Kabir121 The `View` class doesn't support adding other views to it, the `View` class represents a single individual `View`(like, if you want to build a rounded `Button`) and not a group(like in your case when you inflate that layout file).

Comment: This solution should work, but it also mean that there will be viewGroups that always have a single view, and this will always result in more work for the layout phase. I could say a builder paradigm would be better, but then you miss the whole point of extending the view.

Comment: You can inflate a View, you just need to pass the ViewGroup in the constructor.
Be sure to have a ViewGroup which you can pass; some Layout.

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(infService);
    li.inflate(R.layout.test2, **this**, true);
```

You must to use `this`, not null, and change the `false` parameter (boolean AttachToRoot ) to `true`

Comment: To do this, you need to subclass from ViewGroup, not View

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a `ViewGroup` like `FrameLayout` and do:

```
public class View1 extends FrameLayout {

    public View1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.view1, this);
    }
}
```

In the layout XML, use the `<merge` tag to not just add your `view1` layout to the root layout which means we have an empty `FrameLayout` and your defined view beside each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="content" />

</merge>
```

See http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/

Answer (score 3):

Use the code below to inflate your layout, then you can use that view for any purpose. This will give you the most parent layout of your XML file. Type cast and use it accordingly.

```
View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout_name, null);
```

Comment: if i ahve an list view in my View1 class then onlistitem click i am trying to inflate new view but it is not inflatting new view..
Please help someone

Comment: Where is your list item click in custom adapter or in activity.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding in home activity blank view. Because in View1 class you have only inflate view but not add anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin 
`LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_toolbar, null, false)`